# High val_acc, and low val_loss, still wrong predictions with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a set of 300.000+ images, with 38 categories. When I train the images I have a low val_loss and high val_acc, but when I try to predict one of the images (from the training set even), it will not give a correct answer or even close.

The val_loss is around 0.1023 and the val_acc is around 0.9738.

I have tried setting up different images, generated by jpgraph, with different sorts of up and down data for a specific measurement log data from my aquarium computer that has to do with the stability of the water. I have over 5 million rules of mysql data that I generate in 5 minute timeline images with each 4 values. I have uploaded 4 of those images and you can check them out at https://ponne.nu/images/

What I try to do is predict the next step in class, so 5 minutes ahead, with training I show a picture, and then a class (200up, 500down e.g.) based on the data.

So when I train, in any sort of combination, it will give good results on the acc, los, val_acc and val_loss as far as I know is good.

The actual training saving each model (so I could test after each training)

```
Epoch 00023: saving model to /opt/graphs/saved/saved-model-23-0.97.hdf5
Epoch 24/50
37101/37101 [==============================] - 2013s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0968 - acc: 0.9738 - val_loss: 0.1048 - val_acc: 0.9731

Epoch 00024: saving model to /opt/graphs/saved/saved-model-24-0.97.hdf5
Epoch 25/50
37101/37101 [==============================] - 2014s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0968 - acc: 0.9738 - val_loss: 0.1012 - val_acc: 0.9734

Epoch 00025: saving model to /opt/graphs/saved/saved-model-25-0.97.hdf5
Epoch 26/50
37101/37101 [==============================] - 2016s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0968 - acc: 0.9738 - val_loss: 0.1092 - val_acc: 0.9725
```

Parts of the script that trains:

```
FAST_RUN = False
IMAGE_WIDTH=220
IMAGE_HEIGHT=220
IMAGE_SIZE=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
IMAGE_CHANNELS=3 # RGB color
filenames = os.listdir("/opt/images/")
categories = []
for filename in filenames:
    category = filename.split('.')[0]
    if category == '0same':
        categories.append(0)
    elif category == '100up':
        categories.append(1)
    elif category == '200up':
        categories.append(2)
    elif category == '300up':
        categories.append(3)
 (snip)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'filename': filenames,
    'category': categories
})
df['category'] = df['category'].astype('str');
```

And all other categories up to 38 categories that will result in a Dense layer of 38.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(38, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The image generator

```
train_df, validate_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.27, random_state=42)
train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
validate_df = validate_df.reset_index(drop=True)

total_train = train_df.shape[0]
total_validate = validate_df.shape[0]
batch_size=10

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
 )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df,
    "/opt/images/",
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validate_df,
    "/opt/images/",
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)

epochs=50
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_validate//batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train//batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Somewhere in the code I split the validation data / train data into separate chunks, so it will validate on unknown images.

Then the part starts that does not work, in predicting

```
batch_size=1
IMAGE_WIDTH=220
IMAGE_HEIGHT=220
IMAGE_SIZE=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
IMAGE_CHANNELS=3
```

Batch size of 1, and then I insert the model again without the dropouts. After that I load the weights.

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.load_weights('saved/saved-model-33-0.97.hdf5')
```

The actual predict, to give at an image and predict the given class

```
def load_image(img_path, show=False):

    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(220, 220))
    img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)                    # (height, width, channels)
    img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)         # (1, height, width, channels), add a dimension because the model expects this shape: (batch_size, height, width, channels)
    img_tensor /= 255.                                      # imshow expects values in the range [0, 1]
    if show:
        plt.imshow(img_tensor[0])
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
    return img_tensor

img_path = '/opt/testimages/test900up.jpg'
new_image = load_image(img_path)
pred = model.predict_classes(new_image, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
print pred
```

And that is where it is way off, after saving 50 models, it sometimes gets close on each given saved model but only a random image sometimes, could call it more a luck of nature then a real time prediction.

Since the data is more of a type of flowing type, I first tried it with LSTM and just hard data, that gave the same results as the images, very high accuracy and low loss, but the predictions are absolutely wrong. How can it be that the validate data is according to the statistics very good, and predicting on the same images is so bad? What am I doing wrong here? Please notice I am novice programmer.

Comment: Quick comment: You don't need to change the model to remove Dropouts. They are only active when training.

Comment: Also: if you have a time series of data, you don't need to convert it into an image. You can use a convolutional network on 2D data of (time, measurement). That would probably be easier to model.

Comment: When the training data is categorical (i.e. only one label per image) you should use a softmax activation on the output layer and categorical_crossentrophy as loss.

Comment: binary cross entropy loss and sigmoid activation functions  are used for binary classification

Comment: I am kind of stuck in my thinking, so when using categorical_crossentropy and softmax it gives very poor results, so I need to use data again, since it is a timeseries, I could better use LSTM, and try too look ahead at a prediction.

But what I do not understand is if I have a LSTM, I give it a specific time per step right?

Or should I leave the time and just get the data, look x minutes back, and give it a value x minutes in the future to train on? Or is this the wrong aproach?

Comment: And this also confuses me a lot more, the mixmaxscaler, will it do a scaling per row? Or per complete file? For example if I have row 1:

unixtime or timestamp, 2, 4, 3, 5 with output 8

And the second row is:

unixtime or timestamp, 2, 4, 9, 3 -> output.

Is the training file based mix/max from 2 up to 9 or only for that row? So if I do a predict on new data, I can just put one row through the mixmax scaler?

Comment: When you have a time series of values both a Conv1D and LSTM are valid approaches. A convolutional network would typically match patterns in the data... for instance suppose that the signal that you are looking for is a pattern with the numbers x1, x2, x3 regardless of the order that these values appear on the input; then a conv network is a good approach. An LSTM may also be able to recognise such patterns by storing the values in its internal state. Given this is a classification problem the inputs and outputs of the network do not change... they are the same for both approaches.

Comment: One would use a min max scaler only on the columns that should be scaled. E.g. it doesn't make sense to pass the timestamp column to the scaler, as you are not feeding it to the network. You train the min max scaler with the entire data set but you can transform one value at the time.